# DynamicJasper: How to populate report which has List at bean?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

This is my data object

```
public class CandidateExcelModel {
    private int id;
    private String name;    //varchar(50)
    private String email; //   varchar(100)
    private Date dob; //    date  
    private List<String> skill = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

My dynamic report:

```
   for (Iterator<SkillDO> it = job.getSkills().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        SkillDO skills = it.next();
        columns.add(ColumnBuilder.getNew().setColumnProperty(skills.getName(), String.class.getName())
                .setTitle(skills.getName()).setWidth(new Integer(90))
                .addConditionalStyles(conditionalStyles)
                .build());
    }

    drb.addColumn("Id", "id", Integer.class.getName(), 10)
            .addColumn("Name", "name", String.class.getName(), 100)
            .addColumn("E-mail", "email", String.class.getName(), 100)
            .addColumn("dob", "dob", Date.class.getName(), 50)
            .addColumn("Phone Number ", "phoneNumber", String.class.getName(), 25)
            .addColumn("Alternate Number", "alternateNumber", String.class.getName(), 25)
            .addColumn("Address Line", "addressLine", String.class.getName(), 100)
            .setPrintColumnNames(true)
            .setIgnorePagination(true)
            .setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            .setTitle("Sales Report")
            .setUseFullPageWidth(true);
    for (AbstractColumn column : columns) {
        drb.addColumn(column);
    }
```

How to populate this data to report using DynamicJasper? As it contains list  but it should be with no list. The `skill` can only be present in list as it can be variable

Answer (score 1):

Please specify how yo want that list to be shown on the report (i.e. comma sepparated?).
You can declare the field as object ( .addField("skill", Object.class) ) and later add a CustomExpressionColumn or a column with a ValueFormatter where you downcast the "skill" to List and do whatever you want with the list to finally return a string value